# Centre of centre of a matrix in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is question from herstein
Let $F_n$ be denoted for $n×n$ matrix in field $F$

Let $A$ be a matrix in $F_2$

Then let $C(A)$ = { $B : AB=BA$}

And let $C(C(A))$ = { $H: HB =BH  \forall  B \in C(A)$ }

Then all elements in $C(C(A))$ will be of the form $a+bA$

I used Cayley Hamilton theorem to show all the $A^n$ can be written in $a+bA$ but I'm out of idea show it's is true overall.

And in the next question he ask the same for $F_3$ now he says it has the form $a+bA+cA^2$

If there is a way to show this without any use of Cayley Hamilton theorem as the author has not even introduced determinant but has introduced characteristic vector and so...

Comment: How is $C(C(A))$ defined using its own elements ?

Comment: Sorry heh I'll change

Comment: $C(A)$ is usually called the "centralizer" or "commutant" rather than the center.

Comment: Also, presumably $a + bA$ should be $aI + bA$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix

Comment: In general, for any square matrix $A$, we have $C(C(A))=F[A]$. This is a special case of the [*double centraliser theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem). A proof can be found in [a paper by Lagerstrom](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-08/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4.pdf). The are probably simpler proofs.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of a direct proof, for the problem over $F_2$.  There are $3$ cases to consider:

**Case 1:** $A$ has distinct eigenvalues (characteristic values). With a change of basis, we may suppose that $A$ is diagonal. In this case, we see that $C(A)$ consists of all diagonal matrices. Similarly, $C(C(A)) = C(A)$. These matrices are indeed of the form $aI + bA$.

**Case 2:** $A$ has one eigenvalue and a basis of eigenvectors. In this case, $A$ is a multiple of the identity. We find that $C(A) = F_2$ and $C(C(A))$ consists of multiples of $I$.

**Case 3:** $A$ has one eigenvalue and one eigenvector. With a change of basis, we may suppose that $A$ is of the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda & 1\\0 & \lambda}.
$$
Verify that $C(A)$ and $C(C(A))$ are both equal to the set of matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{a & b\\0 & a}.
$$

Comment: Are we using the automorphism structure of P(F_2)P^-1?

Comment: And we see that the same structure of C(C(A)) has dimension two,so it had to be of the form A+Ia?